# Putting list of value into a dataframe as a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import mahotas
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *


data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/ADIP/seperate_ricepests6/seperate_ricepests6/"

image_Humoment = pd.DataFrame()

labels = os.listdir(data_path)
for dirname in labels:
    filepath = os.path.join(data_path, dirname)
    print("Extracting ",dirname," ... ")
    for file in os.listdir(filepath):
        filename = os.path.join(filepath, file)       
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (300,300))
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        df = pd.DataFrame()

        # HUMoments for shape
        image_hu = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(image_gray)).flatten()--------(1)
        df = image_hu.tolist()

    image_Humoment = image_Humoment.append(df, ignore_index=True)

    print(dirname,"ok!")
```

**Results for 3 images (all values going into one column)**

```
               0
0   8.329136e-04
1   3.348686e-10
2   4.307844e-13
3   1.657032e-13
4   1.810802e-26
5  -1.712524e-18
6   4.039908e-26
7   9.305856e-04
8   4.107104e-10
9   1.382715e-13
10  9.868068e-13
11 -3.464484e-25
12 -2.459076e-18
13  1.133319e-25
14  9.058344e-04
15  4.825807e-11
16  2.218821e-15
17  1.050373e-13
18 -1.420554e-27
```

for one image i am getting following results (six features for one image) in image_hu ----(1)

```
 [1.28177255e-03 6.18380479e-09 5.42714183e-12 8.17649469e-12
 3.47643159e-23 3.83751434e-16 4.19301279e-23]
```

**Expected results**

but i am unable to put them into a dataframe as row

for example: one image one row second image second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure on  "getting following results (six features for one image) in image_hu",  Then have a empty dataframe having 6 columns and inside for loop append one row(having 6 values) to the end of the Dataframe like below-

```
image_Humoment = pd.DataFrame(columns=['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3','feature_4','feature_5','feature_6'])
#---- the for loop and other logic
df = image_hu.tolist() # df has 6 values
# Now append 
image_Humoment.loc[len(df)+1] = df
```

try this and let me know.

I am not sure what is the return value of

```
image_hu = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(image_gray)).flatten()
```

But as you mentioned the value to be a list or you are getting the value as list of 6 elements by df= .tolist(),  I am trying to get the next step done for you.

## Append Method

```
image_hu= image_hu.tolist() # sample value [1,2,3,4,5,6]
# convert to dataframe(or pd.series) with same column sequence as image_Humoment 
a_series = pd.Series(image_hu, index = image_Humoment.columns)
# Then append
image_Humoment  = image_Humoment.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: how about append... do we need to write append command to add next row   becuause it is only storing last row

Comment: Oh yes my bad, just change image_Humoment.loc[len(df)+1] = df, or you can use appens as well, but then to append you need to convert the list of 6 values into  dataframe and all. Edited the answer, check that once.

Comment: do we really need to convert the value into list in first place... can't we convert the image_hu results into dataframe and then apply .loc function..    will the append look like this one: image_Humoment = image_Humoment.append(image_Humoment)

Comment: No, the append value has to be a dataframe(or a pd.Series object) and with same column sequence,  So you have to convert that to a pd.DataFrame Object and then you can append.